# @ in link in email is converted twice

Tags: php, email

I am sending mails to people who signed up on my website. I want to give them an option to unsubscribe from my mailing list but a strange bug happens. I have the following php code:

```
$value = $_POST['email'];
```

And somewhere in the body of my mail I have:

```
'<a href="http://mywebsite.com/php/emailremove.php?mail=' . $value . '/">Click here to unsubscribe</a>'
```

When people sign up they fill in their mail address in a form and that form calls my php script. My php script sends it to their mail address (which works fine) and it also includes the unsubscribe link. If I check the link on hotmail I see the @ already changed to %40 (if I copy the link). If I click on the link it changes to %2540, because the browser converted the % again to %25.

The strange thing is, if I open it on my iPhone the link with the mail address still has the @ and if I click on it the link in the browser also has the @... So with hotmail it is converted twice but with mail from iOS it isn't converted at all?

How can I fix this?

Comment: sounds a lot like an encoding issue

Comment: aside from the error this is not a good approach, i could unsub people just by adding any ones email address to your url, better to use a db id\hash

Comment: @Dagon You are right, but since I have a very small website I didn't really care. But now that I think of it, that will also fix this issue. I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: `urlencode($value)` should work